# Is there a Wireless Router that can Access Internet without a Physical Connection?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet

My friend lives in an apartment and has an ipod that need wifi to access the internet.  The apartment does not have internet connection.  This may be a stupid question, but he wants to buy a wireless router to access the internet.  We are getting different answers about using a router.  Can a router be used or even useful if the apartment doesn't have internet access? Is there a router that picks up internet with a physical connection?

Comment: What? It's not like wireless routers pick internet from the air... you have to have an internet connection with a provider (wifi based it's called WiMAX or something like that).

Comment: Who/what will provide your friend with Internet service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you are in reach of a public Wifi, you would need some way to connect to an ISP (Internet Service Provider).

The simplest way to get such connection without cables is to use a 3G/4G Router that "connects to the internet" in the same way a mobile phone does. Therefore you would need a data plan associated with the 3G/4G chip you would use on the router.

Comment: Another addition to this may be to use your smartphone as a wireless hotspot - thus turning it into a wireless router. Be warned, however, it will use your mobile phone's data allowance so take this into consideration - the same as the 3G/4G router answer above.

Comment: I've got a DrayTek router which supports a 3g/4g dongle in the USB port to provde internet access.